# How to make server side rendering in react js v18.2.0?

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

server.js

```
import express from "express";
import fs from "fs";
import path from "path";
import React from "react";
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";
import App from "../src/App";
const app = express();

app.use("^/$", (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve("./build/index.html"), "utf-8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send("Error....");
    }
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToPipeableStream(<App />)}</div>`
      )
    );
  });
});

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "..", "build")));

app.listen(3006, () => {
  console.log("PORt is running on 3006");
});
```

It will give error like ...
Warning: Must provide initial children as second argument to hydrateRoot. Example usage: hydrateRoot(domContainer, )
Uncaught Error: This root received an early update, before anything was able hydrate. Switched the entire root to client rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your index JS file and your usage of `hydrateRoot()`.

`hydrateRoot()` replaces React's render methods and therefore requires both a "root" `div` container and a JSX element. You also do not need to assign `hydrateRoot()` to a variable.

For your app to work, you will need to remove the `root.render()` method and then modify `hydrateRoot()` to include both your `rootElement` and `<App />`. You should also remove `const root =` as this is not required.

It should look something like this:

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

hydrateRoot(
  rootElement,
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your client side index file make this changes. You don't have to use `hydrateRoot`

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import Routes from "./components/Routes";
import reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(reducers, window.INITIAL_STATE, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
);
```

I have created an SSR template with updated packages of react, webpack, react-router

Here is the repository link for your reference - https://github.com/Praful-cs/react-18-webpack-5-server-side-rendering-ssr

Answer (score -1):

This is the index.js file

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { hydrateRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = hydrateRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding details in the answer section